# How actually @font-face work?

Tags: css, browser, font-face

In exp. I have 'Droid Serif' hosted in my server. When user comes to my site and he already installed 'Droid Serif' in his device, is the browser still download my 'Droid Serif' from my server or just ignore it and use the 'Droid Serif' currently installed in his device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only call the attached font in your html/css file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can figure out what should I do.

Comment: Try to avoid @font-face  Use google fonts for faster loading.                                            [Droid Serif Google Font](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Droid+Serif)